# PCRE, match trailing comments after opening left brace

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, pcre

I am trying to match lines in shell scripts, which i.e define a function that has an opening left brace after the function name, such that the regex returns only the left brace and nothing else.

```
function {
  ...
}
```

There may be a trailing comment after the opening brace
function

```
 { # trailing comment
```

which should be allowed in the expression. Otherwise the regex must weed out all other instances of lines that have left braces in them, where these are not opening braces for a function and return "no match". I am trying the following:

```
~/ % pcretest
PCRE version 8.45 2021-06-15

  re> "^[^$]*({)+(?!\W+\w+)\s*#?"
data> {
 0: {
 1: {
data> abc {
 0: abc {
 1: {
data> abc { #
 0: abc { #
 1: {
data> abc ${ #
No match
data> abc { # abc
No match
data>
```

You see, it works well enough, except for the last attempted match

```
data> abc { # abc
```

it return "no match", but I want it to match, whereas I don't want this to match:

```
data> abc { abc
```

Breaking down the regex:

```
"^[^$]*({)+(?!\W+\w+)\s*#?"
```

1. Anchor at beginning of line
2. If a dollar sign precedes the following left brace, return "no match"
3. Negative lookahead: ignore any whitespace after brace and any proper words
4. Follow by zero or more blank space and a possible '#'

Any help?

Comment: ``[^$]`` and ``\W`` match new line symbols too. Try please to replace it with ``[^\r\n$]`` and ``[^\r\n\w]``. May `be `\s`` should also be replaced with ``[^\r\n\S]``

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

```
^.*?^[^$]*({)+(?!\s\w)#?
```

This will match (and not match) like this:

```
~/ % pcretest                                            
PCRE version 8.45 2021-06-15

  re> "^.*?^[^$]*({)+(?!\s\w)#?"
data> {
 0: {
 1: {
data> abc {
 0: abc {
 1: {
data> abc { # def
 0: abc {
 1: {
data> ${
No match
data> abc { def
No match
```

Which is what I wanted.